# Boneh & Soser: Toilet Tank

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Would removing and replacing the cover of a toilet tank pose an issue of Boneh or Soser on Shabbos?

Comment: According to Halachipedia, in the case of covering a "pot", this is allowed on Shabbos, since the covering, only when it is meant to be opened or closed other times. The same applies with making a utensil loosely. It is permitted if it usually is made loosely, but it is forbidden to fit it together tightly or even loosely if it usually fits together tightly [footnote 23 and 25](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Boneh#cite_note-23)

Comment: See also [Mishnah Berurah 313:45](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.313.45?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [Shulchan Aruch 313:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.313.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)